# $ T(g)=0$ for all $g\in L^2\cap L^1$ implies $T(g)=0$ for all $g\in L^2\cap L^p$?

Tags: continuity, operator-theory, lp-spaces

With borel measure.

$T:L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ continuous operator with the norm $|\cdot |_{p}$, $1<p<\infty$.

If $T(g)=0$ for all $g\in L^2\cap L^1$
Then $T(g)=0$ for all $g\in L^2\cap L^p,\ 1<p<\infty$?

I have this:
Because $T$ is continuous and $L^2\cap L^1\cap L^p$ is dense in $L^2\cap L^p$ then holds.
It is correct?

Comment: The question does not make sense. What is the norm w.r.t. which $T$ is a continuous operator? What is the measure space? (Finite measure or any measure?)

Comment: $T:L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ continuous with $|\cdot |_{L^p}$
and borel measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple functions $g=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_kI_{E_k}$ with $E_k$'s having finite measure form  a dense set in $(L^{2}\cap L^{p}, \|.\|_p)$ and these functions are contained in $L^{2}\cap L^{1}$. Hence $T=0$ on $L^{2}\cap L^{p}$.